# Git: unable to push to remote server, SSH works fine

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, git

I tried to make changes to an app that I last modified about 5 years ago and when I tried to push them via git, I got "Permission denied (publickey)". I tried adding the key again, adding public key to authenticated_keys file, reviewed permissions... nothing.

I can connect via ssh with no problem, however. This is the log:

```
git push origin master

git@<IP ADRESS>: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried ssh -Tvvv git@ and here is the log:

https://pastebin.com/UDxKenVj

Could you please point me to the right direction? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I don't see where SSH "connects without problem"? Your log shows it ending up with the exact same message.

Comment: Well, if I connect via ssh 'user@<IP ADDRESS>' then it connects. The problem is when I try to connect using git: 'git@<IP ADDRESS>'

Comment: Please follow the github troubleshooting document [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey), and report on the results.

Comment: I'm not using Github, it's a VPS. But I already followed it and all seems fine according to this document.

Comment: FYI - you'd get that ssh output if user `git` does not exist, so, that's something to check - also, not sure what `authenticated_keys` is, did you mean `authorized_keys` - perhaps that's the problem

Comment: @JonasS.: Well, git@ isn't just a "use Git" prefix - it's a separate account. Did you add your key to _your_ authorized_keys, or did you add it to the `git` user's authorized_keys?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, my mistake. I meant `authorized_keys`
@user1686 well, git user does not have its own directory in /home, so I'm not sure where to add that file. My key is added to regular user's `authorized_keys` file on the server.